# How to linearize the following LP

Tags: linear-programming, absolute-value

I want to minimize $|d_1-d_2|+e1+e2+e3$ where $d_1,d_2,e_1,e_2,e_3>=0$ and $|.|$ denotes the absolute value, for some linear constraints. Is there any way I can linearize the objective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this homework? If you have the problem

min $|d_1-d_2|+e_1+e_2+e_3$

with the constraints
$d_1,d_2,e_1,e_2,e_3\geq0$

then by introducing a new variable $\lambda$ with $\lambda\geq d_1-d_2\geq -\lambda$ we have the following LP whos optimum is just the same as the above

min $\lambda+e_1+e_2+e_3$

with the constraints
$\lambda - d_1 + d_2\geq 0$,
$\lambda + d_1 - d_2\geq 0$
and
$\lambda,d_1,d_2,e_1,e_2,e_3\geq0$

Comment: Thank you. No, I want LP only as a tool. I'm not a mathematician. Regards